# pass formula as function parameter

Tags: r

Below is a function to return a numerical max of a given formula from a certain x range

Everything works fine as follows.

```
  MAX_FN_XY = function(Fn, x1 = 0, x2 = 100)
  {
    x = seq(x1, x2, by= 0.001)
    i = which.max(Fn(x))
    x_max = x[i]
    y_max = Fn(x[i])
    return (c("X*" = x_max,"Y*" = y_max))
  }

  MAX_FN_XY(function(q){q-2*q^2})
```

---

```
Output :

   X    Y

0.250 0.125
```

---

To make the function calling more concise, is it possible to rewrite the script to achieve the following, i.e. getting rid of the "function(q)" part ?

```
MAX_FN_XY(q-2*q^2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, but the Fn argument has to be in quotes. Otherwise R will try to evaluate it as it stands (which is a good thing). Also, your quoted function needs to use the same variable name is the formal argument for the nested function here you wanted it to be q, so it's q).

```
MAX_FN_XY <- function(Fn, x1 = 0, x2 = 100){
  f <- function(q){
    parse(text = Fn)
  }
  x= seq(0, 100, by = 0.1)
  i = which.max(eval(f(x)))
  x_max = x[i]
  y_max = eval(f(x[i]))
  return(c("X*" = x_max, "Y*" = y_max))
}

MAX_FN_XY(Fn = "q-2*q^2")
# X*  Y* 
# 0 -28
```

You should know that using parse makes me queasy and I'm not the only one. I think there's an axiom about how if the answer is parse you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an expression (using "q" as variable) to your procedure as follows (see the documentation in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html)):

```
MAX_FN_XY = function(expr, x1 = 0, x2 = 100) {
  Fn = eval(call("function", as.pairlist(alist(q=)), substitute(expr)))
  x = seq(x1, x2, by= 0.001)
  i = which.max(Fn(x))
  x_max = x[i]
  y_max = Fn(x[i])
  return (c("X*" = x_max,"Y*" = y_max))
}
MAX_FN_XY(q-2*q^2)
# X* 0.25
# Y* 0.125
```